# Ninject сломал EditorFor

Tags: .net, mvc, framework, ninject

Добавил в проект связь с новой таблицей через интерфейсы, использовал Ninjest, но после этого валидация перестала работать, а точнее при подключении в Global.asax.

```
  NinjectModule registrations = new NinjectRegistrations();
  var kernel = new StandardKernel(registrations);
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

перестаёт работать представление Login и Registration

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

в этой строке:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

System.InvalidOperationException: "Имена типов проверки в ненавязчивых правилах проверки должны быть уникальными. Следующие типы проверки встречаются более одного раза: required"

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]        
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Пароли не совпадают")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
```

Контроллер:

```
 public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = null;
                using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
                {
                    user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);
                }
                if (user == null)
                {
                    // создаем нового пользователя
                    using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
                    {
                        db.Users.Add(new User { Email = model.Email,Name = model.Name, Password = model.Password, RoleId=2});
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Email && u.Password == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    // если пользователь удачно добавлен в бд
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, true);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

в Global.asax добавьте

`kernel.Unbind<ModelValidatorProvider>();`